# jQuery: can we get the constantly changed value when animate() is in effect?

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to widen a div:

```
$("#bar").animate({width: '50%'}, 3000);
```

I also want to display the  % value raising from 0% to 50% exactly as it is changing in $("#bar") div.

Please advice, thanks!

Comment: @DOM It is a question on how and he also showed the code that he has...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the `step` option is used for.  Have a look at the documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$("#bar").animate({
    width: '50%'
}, 
{
    duration: 3000,
    step: function(now, fx){
        // update here, now is the current value
        // something like this
        $(this).text(Math.floor(now) + "%");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yFGm4/

Comment: @vega Just beat me on the demo.  I added one as well.  Seems the site isn't auto-updated with comments today.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#bar').animate({width: '50%'}, {
    duration: 3000,
    step: function(now, fx) {
        $('#bar_pct').text(now + '%');
    }
});
```